# how to generate popup in jquery automatically and remove it after fix time

Tags: jquery

I don't know anything about jquery,
I want to generate popup from the database time and then remove it after the fix time which also come from database.

I work over it last 17hours but did nothing.

Comment: A pop-up based on what action? On what html mark up? That you '[worked] at it [for] 17 hours and did nothing' isn't a huge incentive to help.

Comment: hello, can you post any code? What do you mean by "database time"?

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries that could help you. To show popup use [jquery.ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) or [blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/). To close popup after some time just use `setTimeout` function.